# Bubble plot not displaying all points in meta package R

Tags: r, regression, bubble-chart

I am new to coding so I hope I provide all the info necessary to answer this question! I am making a meta regression using the meta package in R and using the bubble function to plot it. I have 173 points to plot, however, it is only displaying 2 points from my dataset on the graph and I'm not sure why.

It says:

```
In bubble.metareg(m.gen.reg, studlab = TRUE, :
  Only first covariate in meta-regression ('population_density') considered in bubble plot. No regression line plotted.
```

I'm not sure what that means and haven't found a way to display all my points. If you know what that message means or how to fix it I'd greatly appreciate it.

[Image of graph currently being produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOvWB.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(meta)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

#took my large dataset and made it smaller to work with

small_dataset_2 <- read.csv("FirstRegressionData.csv",stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  select(Author,Location,Date,value,Lower_Confidence_Limits, Upper_Confidence_Limits,Density_km2) %>%
  mutate(Stand_err =((Upper_Confidence_Limits - value)/1.96)) %>%
  na.omit("small_dataset_2")

#object used for meta analysis

m.gen <- metagen (TE = small_dataset$value,
                  seTE = Stand_err,
                  studlab = Location,
                  data = small_dataset,
                  comb.fixed = FALSE,
                  comb.random = TRUE,
                  overall.hetstat = TRUE,
                  method.tau = "REML")


population_density <- small_dataset_2$Density_km2
                  
m.gen.reg <- metareg(m.gen, ~population_density)  
m.gen.reg

bubble(m.gen.reg, 
       studlab = TRUE,
       xlim = c(1,500),
       ylim = c(0,18),
       regline = TRUE,
       xlab = ("x-axis"),
       ylab = ("y-axis"),
       col.line = "blue"
       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/meta/meta.pdf) for the *meta* package state about the bubble function you are using (bubble.metareg in the instructions):

> It is a scatter plot with the
> treatment effect for each study on the y-axis and **the** covariate used in the meta-regression.

I emphasized **the** to denote only one covariate is identified. So my guess is that *metareg* is not generating the expected object for *bubble*.

When you print m.gen.reg, does it resemble the following from section 8.2 of the [Doing Meta Analysis in R online book](https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/metareg.html)?
[image]

Also, *metagen* is used on **small_dataset**, which is not defined anywhere. I instead see **small_dataset_2**.

Comment: Thank you so much! My m.gen.reg function was producing results that looked like that so I didn't think to check there but it turns out that my population density variable was being read as a character rather than numeric because of the commas. Thank you for the direction and help!